# Blender 3.5 Material preview mode in Cycles, everything appears with a glow, even new objects from scratch

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, shaders

I apologize for this inquiry, I'm sure it's very basic, but I have very little experience with Blender, and I'm asking this question after having tried for hours to solve it and without having found an answer on Google. I'm in Blender 3.5, in Cycles, and I can't understand why every time I create an object with the viewport in material preview mode, it appears with a glow (the object does not have an emissive material). I also find out that a Bloom non-default option appears now in the Shading / Render pass menu of Material preview mode. [image]Thank you very much[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Even the default cube when you create a new file? or only new objects added? Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was just that *Bloom* was activated in Eevee, and I didn't disable it. When I switch back to Cycles, it remains active in the Shading options